# Facebook Comments Stream in Google Maps Infowindow

Tags: google-maps, facebook-comments, infowindow

I’m currently working on a Google Maps project showing places of interest in my local town.  My plan was to use multiple markers on the map to identify different places which when clicked on would open an InfoWindow listing more details about the place.... I also thought it would be good to allow visitors to leave comments and experiences using the Facebook Comments Plugin within the InfoWindow.

However, on further research and reading a couple of other peoples efforts into trying to get Facebook Comments into InfoWindows it doesn’t seem possible... the closet I’ve seen is a chap who managed to get the SAME comments stream appearing in every InfoWindow no matter which marker / point on map was selected.... which isn’t what I want! His conclusion was to build your own comments stream in PHP.

Here's the link to the above article which has a link to the map at work;
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/4wvBdVxPHJ0/vxuYP93N-lgJ

I’m pretty new to Facebook development but certainly don’t mind climbing the learning curve to achieve what I want, but thought it wise to check with the experts here at stackoverflow in case what I am trying to achieve is a non-starter!

Any suggestions, advice and pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: I'm also interested in getting this working - did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I recently managed to do it. 
The trick is to

- insert the content of your infowindow on the end of the page in a hidden div.
- parse this div with `FB.XFBML.parse`
- get the `innerHTML` of your div
- call `infowindow.setContent()` with the innerHTML you got before

If you want different comments in every infowindow you must have a different url for every infowindow's comment plugin: like `http://localhost?infowindow=content1` and `http://localhost?infowindow=content2` for another.

Hope that helped!