# Google Maps API - Facebook comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-maps-api-3

There has been [one other question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701950/facebook-comments-stream-in-google-maps-infowindow), but he hasn't come up with a solution as of yet.

I want to add Facebook comments to each InfoWindow, so that people can comment on particular venues, as a simple review system.

At the moment, I've only been able to add a site-wide comments section, that is always present in the sidebar. When someone comments on it, the comments are visible across the whole site, as opposed to being linked to the individual marker/location.

Is there a way to have a seperate comments section for each item?

Comment: Are you talking about the Comments plugin? That uses a URL to decide what the comments are actually “made upon”. So you would have to set up an individual URL for each of your markers/locations, to create a “connection” between the marker and the comments made upon it.

Comment: the problem with that is that the markers don't have an individual URL. It's all contained within the javascript. Is there a way to create a URL for markers?